# Camera Intent returned Null value

Tags: android, android-intent

i am creating an application using camera. The intent returns null value in samsung mobile. but it is perfectly working in sony mobile. i don't know whats problem in that.My code is here.

```
Intent cameraIntent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
        mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);
        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        Log.i("mediaFile",""+mediaFile);
        return mediaFile;
    }
```

Comment: have you added this permission in your manifest file    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />   ?

Comment: startActivityForResult code ?

Comment: I have added this <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

Comment: i finished startActivithForResult code.i want to know why it is returned null value?

Comment: Feel free to post your `onActivityResult()` implementation. Beyond that, since you already know where the file should be written, have you simply checked the path you requested?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE&& resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}; 
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null, null, null); 
        int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); 
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String capturedImageFilePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

    Toast.makeText(this, capturedImageFilePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, ActivityConst.ENCYIMAGE);
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
```

I am following this in my app its working fine

Comment: File root=new File(----) , it is mostly like getOutputMediaFile method in your code

Answer (score 0):

I have demonstrate to Both the case

1) capture Photo from camera

2) Take a photo from gallary

**Try this is working like charm with me**

```
private String selectedImagePath = "";
    final private int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    final private int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 2;

public Uri setImageUri() {
        // Store image in dcim
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".png");
        Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return imgUri;
    }


    public String getImagePath() {
        return imgPath;
    }

btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), PICK_IMAGE);

            }
        });

        btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            }
        });

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                selectedImagePath = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
                imgUser.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
            } else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
                selectedImagePath = getImagePath();
                imgUser.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
            } else {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }

    }


public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
```